# How do I read data from TSPLIB / tsp files?

Tags: file, traveling-salesman

I was looking for traveling salesman problem data sets and found [this](http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/TSPLIB95/) site.
However, I do not understand how to read the actual data from the extracted "tsp" files on [this](http://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/TSPLIB95/tsp/) webpage... how can I go about doing so?

(I'm just a high school student so please excuse me if this is a stupid question)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the XML instances (http://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/TSPLIB95/XML-TSPLIB/instances/) using some framework from any language.

XML is easier to understand by humans.

Comment: Seriously ? XML is easier ? Compared to what ?

Comment: Compared to the TSP Files.